# Importing a CSV file into lists of lists without using modules

Tags: python, list, csv, append

I'm a beginner and I am stuck at this practice exercise. I am not allowed to use any modules to solve this problem.
I have a csv file with 10 rows representing a different house in each row and 20 columns representing days. For each day, it was recorded whether the temperature in a house fell below 15 deg C. There is no header to the file.

0,2,4,1,1,2,...
2,2,2,1,1,0,...
1,1,1,2,0,0,...
...

I need to perform some calculations such as the average number of times the temp fell below 15 deg C per house and per day. So I'm thinking I need a list of houses which contains all the rows as lists and a list of days which contains sorted values of the correlative columns like [[0,2,1,...],[2,2,1,...],...] to perform these calculations. So far I have tried

```
file = open("filename.csv")
days = []
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    data = line.split(",")
    for x in range(0, len(data)):
        days.append(int(data[x]))
print(days)
```

This is not giving me the list of days like I hoped for. I am getting one big list with all the data in it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the effective way you can do it like this:

```
days = []
with open('filename.csv') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
         line = line.strip() ##Remove space and newline
         numbers = line.split(',')
         days.append(numbers)

print(days)
```

Comment: Firstly this is giving me the list in string but even if I convert number to int I am still getting the same result as with my code. I need the days list to be a list of each column. So the output for days should be [[0,2,1,...],[2,2,1,...],...] but I'm getting [0,2,4,1,1...1,1,1,2,0,0...]. This is the whole data as one big list.

Comment: @SamRa So it can be more easy, I have updated my code